# Outputting a Service Property Value Through a Directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to output a value (from a service) through a element directive so that the html will look like this `<msg msg="alertMsg"></msg>` and out pops a value from the service.

Here is my code thus far:

```
app.directive("msg", ['MsgService', function(MsgService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {//something here to pass MsgService to template },
        template: 'Message:{{MsgService.getAlertMsg()}}'
    };
}]);

app.service('MsgService', function() {        
    this.alertMsg = 'default';
    this.getAlertMsg = function(){
        return this.alertMsg;
    };
    this.setAlertMsg = function(string) {
        this.alertMsg = string;
    };
});
```

HTML would parse/compile to...

```
<msg msg="alertMsg">Message: default</msg>
```

What other code do I need?

If a service wont work directly, Should I access it through a controller?

```
 app.directive("msg", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {    
            getMsg: '&msg'
        },
        controller: 'MsgController',
        template:'Message:{{getMsg()}}'
     };
 }]);

app.controller('MsgController', ['MsgService' , function(MsgService){
    this.getAlertMsg = function(){
        return MsgService.getAlertMsg();
    };
}]);
```

HTML would parse/compile to...

```
<msg msg="getAlertMsg()">Message: default</msg>
```

Sorry for any errors in code or function use, I'm fairly new to Angular.

Comment: How about in the link/controller function of your directive you say angular.extend(scope, MsgService)?

Comment: I didn't know that functionality even existed... Ill read up on it.

Comment: What is your question? The above directive code seems to work fine.

Comment: I was wanting to not have to use the MsgController and just access any MsgService function from the directive template, picking what function to execute by setting msg="functionName" in directive tag. (make sense?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `link` function of the directive. This function is called once for every rendered instance of your directive. It receives, among other things, the scope of your directive. You can extend your scope very easily with the result of calling the `MsgSevice.getAlertMsg()` service method:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive("msg", ['MsgService', function(MsgService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        template: 'Message:{{msg}}',
        link: function (scope, $element, attrs) {
            scope.msg = MsgService.getAlertMsg();
        }
    };
}]);

app.service('MsgService', function() {
    this.alertMsg = 'default';
    this.getAlertMsg = function(){
        return this.alertMsg;
    };
    this.setAlertMsg = function(string) {
        this.alertMsg = string;
    };
});
```

Later on, I presume you will want to just display the alert message from the `msg` DOM attribute of the `msg` directive. Achieving this is much more simple, since AngularJS is already prepared for this common use case. The solution involves creating an isolate scope. The isolate scope can be populated with properties from the parent environment. One possibility is to use the value of a DOM attribute from your directive's element using the "@" syntax. In this case you won't even need the entire `MsgService` service:

```
app.directive("msg", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            "msg": "@"
        },
        template: 'Message:{{msg}}'
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Razvan for the very detailed answer. I will work for me. I am using the MsgService with all my controllers. Messages will be displayed through directives with the scope isolated to what the directive sets it to. I will be able to pick what message to display through an attribute value on the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to set the service on your scope and use that in your template:

```
app.directive("msg", ['MsgService', function(MsgService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { },
        template: 'Message:{{MsgService.getAlertMsg()}}',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.MsgService = MsgService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for and will definitely do, I should be able to do exactly what I want with that attrs param. Thankyou!